# Set Apple Script App as custom browser on macOS mojave

Tags: macos, applescript, mojave

I followed instructions here: [Default Browser .plist location](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219582/default-browser-plist-location)

But it does't work. My custom app doesn't show up in the list of browsers to choose from in system settings:

[image]

I have tried:

- calling /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister on the modified plist file.
- moving the custom app to /Applications

What does it take to get this to work on macOS mojave? Thanks

Comment: for a weird approach, I'd take the plist of the chrome app & put it in your app's "show package contents". Remove all the extra info or modify them to point to appropriate  executables

Comment: I solved the problem using `swda` from SwiftDefaultApps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem using SwiftDefaultApps command line tool `swda`. It works. Although, this box now shows up blank in system setting.

`swda` is located inside the zip file of the latest release at https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/releases

[image]